# Replacing hexagons with destroyed hexagons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to replace the destroyed hexagons with other standing hexagons. Existing hexagons should fall from the top. For example if I destroy (0,2) positioned hexagon in the picture below, the top left hexagon which position of that hexagon is (0,0) should be moved to (0,2) position and i should create a new hexagon and put it on (0,0) which is empty now because we moved the hexagon on (0,0) to (0,2) earlier.

I have a two dimensional array that stores all the references of hexagons with an index of the hexagon's coordinate (x,y).

**--IMPORTANT--**

Moving the objects is not important. The important part is we have to know which hexagon will be replaced with another. We have to tell the ARRAY that we changed those hexagons and the hexagons that were just moved or created should have exactly one reference in the index of their new (x,y) positions.

**VIDEO FOR BETTER EXPLAINING WHAT I WANT TO DO**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QYhq0qwFmmY

Any ideas or help would be appreciated!

Hexagon Coordinate system (ignore red arrows)
[image: Hexagon Coordinates]

[image: Hexagon Grid]

```
public void CreateGrid(int gridWidth, int gridHeight)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < gridHeight; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < gridWidth; x++)
            {
                GameObject Hexagon = Instantiate(HexagonPre, Vector2.zero, Quaternion.identity, HexGrid);

                    int RandColor = Random.Range(0, 5);
                    if (RandColor == 0)
                    {
                        Hexagon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.blue;
                    }
                    else if (RandColor == 1)
                    {
                        Hexagon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.red;
                    }
                    else if (RandColor == 2)
                    {
                        Hexagon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.green;
                    }
                    else if (RandColor == 3)
                    {
                        Hexagon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.yellow;
                    }
                    else if (RandColor == 4)
                    {
                        Hexagon.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = Color.cyan;
                    }

                Vector2 gridPos = new Vector2(x, y);
                Hexagon.transform.position = CalcWorldPos(gridPos);
                Hexagon.GetComponent<HexCoordinates>().Coordinates = new Vector2Int(x, y);
                Hexagon.transform.name = "X: " + x + " | Y: " + y;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Code for destroying hexagons**

```
   if (MatchedColors == 2)
                    {
                        if(!HexToBeDestroyed.Contains(Hexagons[x, y].gameObject))
                        HexToBeDestroyed.Add(Hexagons[x, y].gameObject);

                        if (!HexToBeDestroyed.Contains(Hexagons[x - 1, y].gameObject))
                            HexToBeDestroyed.Add(Hexagons[x - 1, y].gameObject);

                        if (!HexToBeDestroyed.Contains(Hexagons[x - 1, y - 1].gameObject))
                            HexToBeDestroyed.Add(Hexagons[x - 1, y - 1].gameObject);
                    }

                    MatchedColors = 0;
                }

            }

        }
    }


    foreach (GameObject G in HexToBeDestroyed)
    {
        if (G != null)
        {
            Destroy(G.gameObject);

        }
    }
```

Comment: For the empty spaces after swapping all hexagons with each other, we should create new ones and fill the empty spaces from the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation for code is in comments:

```
void HexagonFall(GameObject[,] hexArray)
{
    // Handle fall for base columns and for offset columns
    for (int offset = 0 ; offset < 2 ; offset++)
    {
        // Handle fall for each column at current offset
        for (int x = 0 ; x < hexArray.GetLength(0) ; x++)
        {
            int bottomYIndex = hexArray.GetLength(1) - offset - 1;

            // List of indices of where each hexagon in that column will come from.
            // We will fill from bottom to top.
            List<Vector2Int> sourceIndices = new List<Vector2Int>();

            for (int y = bottomYIndex ; y >= 0 ; y-=2)
            {
                // HexExists returns true if the hex isn't empty. 
                // Something along the lines of ` return input!=null; `
                // depending on what "empty" hexes look like in the array

                if (HexExists(hexArray[x,y]))
                {
                    sourceIndices.Add(new Vector2Int(x,y));
                }
            }

            // We have a list of where to get each bottom hexes from, now do the move/create
            for (int y = bottomYIndex; y >= 0 ; y-=2)
            {
                if (sourceIndices.Count > 0)
                {
                    // If we have any available hexes in column,
                    // use the bottommost one (at index 0)
                    hexArray[x,y] = hexArray[sourceIndices[0].x, sourceIndices[0].y];

                    // We have now found a home for hex previously at sourceIndices[0].
                    // Remove that index from list so hex will stay put.
                    sourceIndices.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                else 
                {
                    // Otherwise, we need to generate a new hex
                    hexArray[x,y] = MakeNewHexAt(new Vector2Int(x,y));
                }

                // Tell the hex about its new home
                hexArray[x,y].GetComponent<HexCoordinates>().Coordinates = new Vector2Int(x, y);
                hexArray[x,y].transform.name = "X: " + x + " | Y: " + y;
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

In your hex destroying code, I would change HexToBeDestroyed to be a `List` of `Vector2Int` so you can set the array references to null immediately when you `Destroy` the gameobject:

```
List<Vector2Int> HexToBeDestroyed = new List<Vector2Int>();

// ...

if (MatchedColors == 2)
{
    if(!HexToBeDestroyed.Contains(new Vector2Int(x, y))
        HexToBeDestroyed.Add(new Vector2Int(x, y));

    if (!HexToBeDestroyed.Contains(new Vector2Int(x - 1, y))
        HexToBeDestroyed.Add(new Vector2Int(x - 1, y));

    if (!HexToBeDestroyed.Contains(new Vector2Int(x - 1, y - 1)))
        HexToBeDestroyed.Add(new Vector2Int(x - 1, y - 1));
}

// ...

foreach (Vector2Int V in HexToBeDestroyed)
{
    if (Hexagons[V.x,V.y] != null)
    {
        Destroy(Hexagons[V.x,V.y]);
        Hexagons[V.x,V.y] = null;
    }
}
```

As far as moving the hexes goes, I would add this in the `Update` of `HexCoordinates`:

```
float fallSpeed = 0.5f;

Vector2 goalWorldPosition = GS.CalcWorldPos(Coordinates);

transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, goalWorldPosition, fallSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198747/discussion-on-answer-by-ruzihm-replacing-hexagons-with-destroyed-hexagons).

Comment: I edited your code to fix a bug. I think there should be no offset in this line: for (int x = 0 ; x < hexArray.GetLength(0) - offset ; x++) since i got error whenever the last hexagon on an odd rows destroyed and had to be replaced but did not. I removed the offset, now it is working fine. Still trying to figure out the 3 hexagon swapping bug tho :)

Comment: @FaTaLL Oh, I didn't see that the offset ones had the same length. Silly me. Thanks!